# PHPUnit: bootstrap file isn't included via phpunit.xml but works well if i use the --bootstrap directive

Tags: phpunit, configuration-files, bootstrapping

Ok, i really don't understand what is happening with my PHPUnit's bootstrap file.

I have a folder structure like the following one:

```
[Root]
- joo_component
-- administrator
-- site
-- Tests
--- admin
--- site
--- bootstrap.php
--- phpunit.xml
- vendor
```

In the phpunit.xml file, i have the following code:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php" colors="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite... [all the things that go here]</testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Now, if i call PHPUnit explicitly specifying the bootstrap file all works well: the testing starts and properly signals errors and all other things it has to signal.
This is the command that works:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --bootstrap="joo_component/Tests/bootstrap.php" joo_component/Tests
```

But, if i try to launch the testing without explicitly specifying the bootstrap file but specifying it in the phpunit.xml file it seems like the bootstrap file isn't loaded.

```
vendor/bin/phpunit joo_component/Tests
```

Is there anyone who can help me underdtand why this happens? Is there a way to force PHPUnit to tell me which bootstrap file it is using to load the test suites?

Comment: It appears to be having problems finding the bootstrap file, since it's not in the same directory that you are in when you run the command. I tend to put the phpunit.xml file in the root, and run PHPUnit from there as well

Comment: Yes, i think the same thing. But how to know which is the path used? Anyway, I'll try to put the phpunit.xml file in the root, but i'd really like to know how to output somewhere the path used so to have more control on my code and how it is executed.

Comment: Moving the phpunit.xml file to the root works: now the tests are well executed and the bootstrap file correctly loaded.

Remains my question: how to output the paths used by PHPUnit?

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. Moving it to root did not work for me, however.